# why catkin package is still needed at ROS runtime?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't wave it out of my head...
Why we still need catkin when we run ROS? Isn't it a package building tool? Why it's still needed at runtime?

Because in my understanding, catkin is a tool we used to build packages, almost like an enhanced version of cmake.
So normally cmake is not needed when we run executables right?

But when I tried to run ROSCORE in my own environment without catkin package, I got errors when importing.

$ roscore

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/bin/roscore", line 72, in 
    import roslaunch
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 57, in 
    from .launch import ROSLaunchRunner
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 55, in 
    from roslaunch.nodeprocess import create_master_process, create_node_process
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py", line 50, in 
    from roslaunch.node_args import create_local_process_args
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/node_args.py", line 53, in 
    import roslib.packages
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 54, in 
    import roslib.stacks
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in 
    import roslib.packages
  File "/sdcard/ros_runtime/runtime_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in 
    from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find
ImportError: No module named catkin.find_in_workspaces`

Does catkin serve as other functions other than a building tool? What's the concept of "workspace" here? It is different than "build" and "devel" workspace right?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339563/why-catkin-package-is-still-needed-at-ros-runtime?/) by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-10**:
Could you be specific?

What sort of use are you seeing?

Note: there is `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin` and there are Python modules and C++ libraries with the name `catkin` in them.

The latter may be used by nodes to query and introspect the ROS filesystem (ie: a workspace).

**Comment by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on 2019-12-10**:
Sorry for being unclear. I modified the question. Could you please take another look? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Python modules missing (`catkin.*`) are provided by the Python package [catkin_pkg](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg). It is responsible for:

- finding packages (also in the case after they have been built and installed)
- parsing the package manifest
- extracting information like registered plugins fe.g. available displays for `rviz`)

So yes, you do need that Python package at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0